# Run django migrate in docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am building a Python+Django development environment using docker. I defined Dockerfile files and services in docker-compose.yml for web server (nginx) and database (postgres) containers and a container that will run our app using uwsgi. Since this is a dev environment, I am mounting the the app code from the host system, so I can easily edit it in my IDE.

The question I have is where/how to run migrate command.

In case you don't know Django, migrate command creates the database structure and later changes it as needed by the project. I have seen people run migrate as part of the compose command directive `command: python manage.py migrate && uwsgi --ini app.ini`, but I do not want migrations to run on every container restart. I only want it to run once when I create the containers and never run again unless I rebuild.

Where/how would I do that?

Edit: there is now an open issue with the compose team. With any luck, one time command containers will get supported by compose. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896

Comment: Why not use a `RUN` directive in dockerfile that will run when creating the image?

Comment: Two reasons. The migrate command runs in one container (the app server), but affects another container (posgres database) and compose builds are sequential. And second reason, shared volumes are not mounted during build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `RUN` because as you mentioned in the comments your source is mounted during running of the container.

You cannot use `CMD` either since you don't want it to run everytime you restart the container.

I recommend using `docker exec` manually after running the container. I do not think there is a way to automate this inside a `dockerfile` or `docker-compose` because of the two reasons I gave above.

Comment: One suggestion I have found was to use a one-time container that depends on the database, starts up, mounts the shared volume with the code in it, runs the command and exits. That sounds like a plan, but I am not sure how to prevent this container from starting again on the next `docker-compose up`. Maybe you are right and manual is the way to go. If I don't get any other suggestions, I will accept your answer.

Comment: One way to do it independent of docker would be to have a script that runs every time container runs. Inside the script after running your `migrate` command create an empty file which indicates the state of flag in the mounted location. Next time container starts the script checks if the file exists skips running `migrate` command otherwise creates it and runs your `migrate` command.

Comment: That might be a good idea. I was thinking of writing a shell script to check for tables in the database, but that seemed convoluted and if I am going to write convoluted scripts, I might as well script my container creation and skip compose altogether. Checking for a file is easier and can probably be done straight in the command directive in compose config.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a tool for managing project tasks. [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/) is a tool designed to handle these tasks (disclaimer: I am the author of this tool).

You can see an example of how to run a migration here: https://github.com/dnephin/dobi/tree/master/examples/init-db-with-rails. The example uses rails, but it's basically the same idea as django.

You could setup a task called `migrate` which would run the command in a container and write the data to a volume. Then when you start your `docker-compose` containers, use that volume as the source for your database service.

Comment: Interesting tool. I will look into it. I am not doing CI though, so I might just go with using shell aliases for a few docker exec commands

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896 is finally resolved now by the new [service profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) introduced with [`docker-compose` 1.28.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.28.0). With `profiles` you can mark services to be only started in specific profiles:

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    # ...

  postgres:
    # ...

  uwsgi:
    # ...

  migrations:
    profiles: ["cli-only"] # profile name chosen freely
    # ...
```

```sh
docker-compose up # start only your app services, no migrations
docker-compose run migrations # run migrations on-demand
```

Answer (score -2):

`docker exec -it container-name bash`

Then you will be inside the container and you can run any command you normally do when you develop without using docker.

Comment: I need to run it before the app container starts. Besides, I want a single command solution.